# Achieve one to many relationship Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to achieve one to many relationship. I know how to do basic one to many relationship between requestor id and userid.

**My question is  How to refer gtlUserId(resourceRequestTable) to gtlUserId (User table) as by default spring is mapping gtlUserId (resourceRequestTable) to userId in user table**

[image: Logical ER]

Comment: "mappedBy" is supposed to be the FIELD in the related class that links back to this class. It is currently WRONG (or at least based on the very abbreviated code posted that's all we can guess)

Comment: @NeilStockton can you give a example based on this ER mentioned above

Comment: Why don't you do an internet SEARCH, for JPA documentation? You presumably selected a JPA provider, and the docs for that provider would tell you how to define a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL relation. TABLES are not of relevance in a JPA mapping, FIELDS are

Comment: @NeilStockton  i solved other problem but now the problem i have is How to refer gtlUserId(resourceRequestTable) to gtlUserId (User table) as by default spring is mapping gtlUserId (resourceRequestTable) to userId in user table

Comment: As already said ... "TABLES are not of relevance in a JPA mapping, FIELDS are". You have not posted your classes. Also you should NOT change the question half way through ... create a new question

Answer (score 0):

It has some Ways.
I think you should give a specific  way during all project !
As My experience each many to one must be a Drop Down in Client side .
However in your Table ResourceTypeEntity should be drop down inside ResourceRequesTable when value of option is Id[primary Key].
Also Your table not seems good design why two many to one map to same table? it may cause 3NF problem in DB also pay attention Cascade it when Parent Table related to other Parent is not good Design ,Keep it simple with uni Direction Many to One And force user to delete manually parent is better ,CaseCade Delete when Parent has related to other table will make exception handling and testing too hard.
please take  a look https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/